# WSo2 custom handler: Class Not Found error

Tags: wso2

I wrote a custom authentication handler based on the instructions in the user guide.

I placed my jar /repository/components/lib and tried to add it to a specific API from admin console -> Service bus -> Service view, but received class not found error in the log.

The only way I was able to make it work was a workaround of "pushing" it to one of WSO2's deployment jars (org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_5.0.3.jar). When added to this jar and re-starting WSo2, I got the handler working all right.

But I guess this workaround is not the proper way to do it... Is this a CLASSPATH issue or something that I'm missing in the process to make it work?

Comment: what is the classnotfound error?can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Seems u are using wso2 APIM. Share the version and log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further checking, turns out my JAR had been corrupted for some reason. I built it again and it works now.

For the benefit of anyone from the community who attempt to try this, I'll post the steps I did (working with APIM 1.10.0)

1) The JAR file:

```
$ cd /home/olahav/wso2/wso2am-1.10.0/repository/components/lib
$ jar tf extensions.jar
...
org/wso2/carbon/test/OferAPIAuthenticationHandler_1.class
```

2) The API template:

```
<handlers xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<handler class="org.wso2.carbon.test.OferAPIAuthenticationHandler_1"/>
#foreach($handler in $handlers)
    <handler xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" class="$handler.className">
        #if($handler.hasProperties())
        #set ($map = $handler.getProperties() )
        #foreach($property in $map.entrySet())
        <property name="$!property.key" value="$!property.value"/>
        #end
        #end
    </handler>
    #end
</handlers>
```

3) Since this is a template, need to re-create the API. Then checking in the service view (via https://localhost:9443/carbon) you can see the handler added to the list of handlers:

```
    <handlers>
        <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.test.OferAPIAuthenticationHandler_1"/>
        <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.CORSRequestHandler">
            <property name="apiImplementationType" value="ENDPOINT"/>
        </handler>
        <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler"/>
        <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.APIThrottleHandler">
            <property name="id" value="A"/>
            <property name="policyKeyResource" value="gov:/apimgt/applicationdata/res-tiers.xml"/>
            <property name="policyKey" value="gov:/apimgt/applicationdata/tiers.xml"/>
            <property name="policyKeyApplication" value="gov:/apimgt/applicationdata/app-tiers.xml"/>
        </handler>
        <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageHandler"/>
        <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtGoogleAnalyticsTrackingHandler">
            <property name="configKey" value="gov:/apimgt/statistics/ga-config.xml"/>
        </handler>
        <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler"/>
    </handlers>
```

That's it!

Thanks for anyone who helped me through.